# $T:V \to W$ and $S: W \to V$ such that $T\circ S = I_w$ but $S\circ T \neq I_V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Working through some questions and I'm stuck on the following:

Find an example of vector spaces $V$ and $W$, and linear transformations $T:V \to W$ 
and $S: W \to V$, such  that $T\circ S$ = $I_w$ but $S\circ T \neq I_V.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $V=\Bbb R^3$ and $W=\Bbb R^2$. Consider the linear transformations $T\colon V\to W$ and $S\colon W\to V$ defined by,

$$S(x,y)=(x,y,0)\quad, \quad T(x,y,z)=(x,y)$$

Then, note that we have,

$$(T\circ S)(x,y)=T(S(x,y))=T(x,y,0)=(x,y)=I_W(x,y)$$

But,

$$(S\circ T)(x,y,z)=S(T(x,y,z))=S(x,y)=(x,y,0)$$

and this is equal to $I_V(x,y,z)$ iff $z=0$, i.e., it's not equal to $I_V(x,y,z)$ in general.

As a specific example to show that $(S\circ T)(x,y,z)$ is not necessarily equal to $I_V(x,y,z)$, take the example $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, if $T\circ S = I_W$, then we know that $S$ must be injective, since it has a left-inverse.  We also see that $T$ is surjective for similar reasons.  This helps us think of some examples.  The easiest one I can think of is setting $W = \mathbb{R}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^2$.  We then let $S:V\to W$ be the inclusion map $S:x\mapsto (x, 0)$, and $T:X\to V$ be the projection map $T:(x, y)\mapsto x$.  It is pretty easy to verify that $T\circ S$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$, but $S\circ T$ is not the identity on $\mathbb{R}^2$, since, for example, $(S\circ T)(1, 1) = (1, 0)$.